# SharePoint Online Custom Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, json

I would like to change the background color of a SharePoint calendar list item when a pattern is entered in the title with JSON coding. for example, if "ABC" is used in the title, then the background color of the appointment is changed to something other than the default. I have tried the below code but it does not work.

```
 "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
    "debugMode": true,
    "elmType": "div",
    "Style": {
        "Color": {
            "operator": "?",
            "operands": [
                {
                    "operator": "==",
                    "operands": [
                  {
                  "operator": "toString()",
                  "operands": [
                  "@currentField"
                  ]
                  },"ABC"
                  ]
                                        }, "green"
                ]
               }
               }
               }
```

Comment: Just to confirm that you are not trying to get the color changed in the calendar view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct JSON assuming you are trying to columning formatting in the modern list/libraries:

```
{
"$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"attributes": {
    "class": {
        "operator": "?",
        "operands": [
            {
                "operator": "==",
                "operands": [
                    {
                        "operator": "toString()",
                        "operands": [
                            "@currentField"
                        ]
                    },
                    "ABC"
                ]
            },
            "sp-field-severity--good","nocolor"
        ]
    }
}}
```

You can replace "nocolor" class with "sp-field-severity--severeWarning" if you want red color for the items not matching the condition i.e 'ABC'.

More details [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-column-formatting/tree/master/samples/text-conditional-format)

Comment: Thank you! It did work for a regular modern list but it is not working for calendar items. are there any solutions to change the background on calendar items based on a text pattern in the title?

Comment: Column formatting will only work in the modern experience so if you want to display in the Calendar app 'All Events' you will need to changed the default experience to Modern (under list advanced settings).  If you want to show colors in the calendar view you need calendar overlays not column formatting.

Comment: Is it possible to use custom class instead of the pre-defined sp-field-severity--good

Comment: @Kannan, you could style.  Custom class might work if the css is already included on the master page, though I haven't tried this.